# How to fix "The Procedure entry point SDL_ceilf could not be located in the dynamic link library"

Tags: c++, visual-studio, sdl-2

Im making a game in SDL2 and for the text i need to include SDL2_ttf.h. But when I start to run the program it give me the error: "Entry Point Not Found"

[image: Error window] "Entry Point Not Found"

I downloaded the SDL2 TTF from https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_ttf/ under Development libraries  " SDL2_ttf-devel-2.0.15-VC.zip".

[image: My Folders]

And my Visual Studio Project settings:

[C++ Additional include directories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2Vsd.jpg)

[C++ Linker settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUhAh.jpg)

[C++ Linker input settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lNuws.jpg)

Comment: This means you have a dll conflict which could be caused by an old dll in one of the folders that are listed in your PATH environment variable.

Comment: Wait a minute why are the SDL dlls in your binary folder from 2017? The files in the 2.0.15 download are from 2019.

Comment: I retracted my answer because I now think the problem is a different type of dll conflict. I believe your SDL2 and SDL2_ttf are mismatched.

Comment: @drescherjm what do you mean "mismatched" i downloaded both SDL2 and SDL2_ttf -> the latest versions..

Comment: SDL2 binaries are from 2017, SDL2_ttf are from 2019.

Comment: I just checked and there are SDL2 2.0.9 binaries from Oct 2018. https://www.libsdl.org/download-2.0.php

Comment: @drescherjm if i replace the old SDL with the new one everything should run just fine ?

Comment: You may have to do a clean build of your project.

Comment: [This](http://lists.libsdl.org/pipermail/commits-libsdl.org/2017-November/002386.html) looks like the SDL2_ceilf was added in Nov 2017 (so later than your current binaries).

Answer (score 1):

Your SDL2 binaries are too old for the SDL2_ttf binaries you are using. Your SDL2 binaries are from May of 2017. From the following mailing list post it appears that the `SDL_ceilf` function was added in November of 2017: http://lists.libsdl.org/pipermail/commits-libsdl.org/2017-November/002386.html

To fix update your SDL2 binaries: https://www.libsdl.org/download-2.0.php

and do a clean build of your project.